# Would Android be able to handle a karaoke app?

Tags: android

I want to write a Karaoke app [edit] which captures the user with the front facing camera as they sing over the music that the device itself is playing (they would see themselves in the preview window as well as the lyrics across the bottom of the screen) [/edit] and am curious how resource heavy the video capture is, and if it would make playing music and displaying text over (or beneath) the video preview too choppy or clunky.

What would be the best way to optimize audio playback so as to allow the video capture portion all the processing resources it needs? Is this even doable? (I notice that audio stops when I turn the camera on, but I'm guessing that that's something that the built in video capture app does manually simply to help the user not record the audio coming from the device).

I'm assuming I'd be doing this on the xoom, though I'd be delighted to hear that the Tab could handle such an app as well.

All thoughts welcome.

Comment: Should be easy to test this with just the audio playback and video recording. I wouldn't worry about the lyrics overlay, since I doubt that would impact performance much.

Comment: This is rather broad for Stack Overflow. Did you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.karaokeanywhere.net/

So I'm sure it can.

But I'm not sure what video capture has to do with karaoke, could you please elaborate?

I would picture a karaoke app would just stream the lyrics while the song plays, and just have a generic(or completely blank) background.

Comment: sorry, I should have been clearer... the point of the app is to record people (with user facing camera) AS they sing the song. That's where my resource concern lies.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I ran some tests and it definitely works. More details on problems/solutions as I get further into dev.

Comment: If you want to update your question or add a comment, update your question or add a comment :)

Comment: yeah, I realize it's a bit subjective, but I thought someone might have an answer and if not then someone else might benefit from my looking into this topic. No worries, though.  And yes, I've read the FAQ.